# AVPlayer not playing .mov files

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"thoughtcastAnimate_v02" withExtension:@"mov"];

    // create an AVPlayer
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

    // create a player view controller
    AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    controller.player = player;
    [player play];

    // show the view controller
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
    controller.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

This works fine with an mp4 file. But I need a .mov file to be played! This is for my application splash screen. I added the .mov file to the assets. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Try change order of calls, first `addSubiew`, then call `play`.

Comment: Not working. There is just a black screen with a loading circle that is infinite.

Comment: I just noticed my line of code NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"thoughtcastAnimate_v02" withExtension:@"mov"]; returns NIL
https://snag.gy/Bg46FT.jpg

Comment: is it actually a .mov? It appears to have no extension from your screenshot.

Comment: Problem solved. I needed to add it to the Build Bundle..

Comment: can you help me for play video using internet url. means that url coming from server with .MOV extension. I am playing in AVPlayerViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add my mov file to the Build Phases

Comment: how to add mov file in build phase.

Comment: Xcodeproj -> Targets -> YourApp -> Build Phases tab -> Copy Bundle Resources -> + symbol at bottom @ChandanJee